# Breeze does not update my list when using MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges

Tags: breeze

I have this code:

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from(endpoint)
    .withParameters(withParameters)
    .toType(entity)
    .using(breeze.MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges)
    .noTracking(false)
    .using(manager)
    .execute()
    .then(_extractResponseResult)
    .catch(_doSomethingElse);

function _extractResponseResult(response) {
    console.log(">>. results: ", results);

    return results;
}
```

and the result looks something like this:

```
Myitem {
  entityAspect : {...},
  name : 'item name',
  lists : Array[1]
}
```

Whenever I execute the `breeze.EntityQuery.from()` method, it always returns an un-updated list. Which is really starting to tick me off. How do i make sure it's updated? Like when the backend clears the list, there shouldn't be any lists left, but when I do `breeze.EntityQuery.from()` the list is still there even though the stupid network console says, "oh the list is empty" so the lists on the breeze response should be empty but then i look and it's not empty. All the other properties gets updated except from the list.

My metadata looks like this:

```
addType({
name: 'MyEntity',
dataProperties: {
    id: {nullOk: false, isPartOfKey: true},
    name: {}
},
navigationProperties: {
    lists: {
        hasMany: true,
        entityTypeName: 'MyList',
        associationName: 'Foo_MyList'
    }
}
});
```

I tried clearing the cache as suggested [here](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/entitymanager-and-caching.html), but unfortunately, my lists are actually displayed in another part of the screen on the SAME PAGE (the user just makes the list part of MyItem via checkboxes), and doing the detaching thing, removes those lists on the screen as well because they are the same entity after all, same id, which is not what I intend to do.

Comment: Handling server-side deletes is basically cache-coherency, and is a [hard problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22192116/2517406).

Answer (score 0):

Handling server-side deletes is basically a cache-coherency issue, and is a [hard problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192116/2517406).

In this case, you might be able to use the [retrievedEntities](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_executeQuery) property of the returned data object to inform the client about which items in the list have been returned.

In the example below, I've assumed that the query returns a MyItem entity with all its MyList objects included (expanded) in the server response.  The retrievedEntities list will contain all the MyList entities, so if one is missing, we assume it has been deleted on the server.

```
manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
    var myItem = data.results[0];
    var retrieved = data.retrievedEntities;
    myItem.lists.forEach(function (myList) {
        if (retrieved.indexOf(myList) < 0) {
            // already deleted on the server
            myList.entityAspect.setDetached();
        }
    })
    return myItem;
});
```